# Find domain of logarithmic function

Tags: functions

I'm a little confused about this question , I know that fraction denominator needs to be > 0 , so if denominator is quadractic equation i know how to solve ,
But since denominator is > 0 , I dont know how to solve , can anyone help me ?

$f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\log \left(\frac{3x-x^2}{2}\right)}$

Comment: Do you know the critical value method for solving inequalitie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- You also need to have $$\log\left(\frac {3x-x^2}{2}\right)\geq 0 $$ for the square root of that function to be defined, and this implies $$\frac{3x-x^2}{2} \geq 1 \iff 3x-x^2 \geq 2$$

$$\iff3x-x^2 - 2 \geq 0 \iff x^2 - 3x+2 = (x-1)(x-2) \leq 0.$$

The quadratic will be less than or equal to zero when exactly one and only one factor $\leq 0$:

So the domain is, in fact, $$x \in [1, 2],\; \text{ alternatively }\, 1\leq x\leq 2$$ I stand corrected: one or both factors can be zero. Else, one must be  negative the other positive.

Comment: so i need to find x from numerator ?

Comment: Hint: examine the interval $x\in [1, 2]$, and compare to what happens when $x \notin [1, 2]$.

Comment: Great Great Job.

Answer (score 1):

we have $log$ under square root so $\frac{3x-x^2}{2}\geq 1$

Comment: so I need to solve this quadratic function 3x - x2 > 1 ?

Comment: yes and you get $-x^2+3x-2\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

it must be $$\frac{3x-x^2}{2}\geq 1$$ this is equivalent to $0\geq x^2-3x+2$ and this is equivalent to
$$0\geq (x-1)(x-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

The function under the radical must be positive, meaning that the argument of the logarithm must exceed $1$. So

$$\frac{3x-x^2}2\ge1,$$
or
$$x^2-3x+2\le0.$$

By factoring,
$$(x-1)(x-2)\le0.$$
This occurs when the factors are different signs, i.e.

$$1\le x\le2.$$